# chart.js axes tick callback function doesn't receive any global data

Tags: javascript, chart.js

When i try to use a global variable in this function i always get undefined.
On the y axis I need to have fixed values, for example: Fault and Healthy, but chart.js work dynamically and add values.

```js
ticks: {
  beginAtZero: true,
  max: this.numberOfMax,
  // autoSkip: false,
  callback: function(value, index, values) {
    console.log(value)
    if (values.length == 7) {
      console.log(this.currentClicked)
      switch(value) {
        case 0: 
        return "Healthy"
        case 1.0:
          return "Inner Race Fault"
        case 2.0:
          return "Outer Race Fault"
        case 3.0:
          return "Roller Element Fault"
      }
    } else if (values.length == 11) {
      switch(value) {
        case 0: 
        return "Healthy"
        case 1.0:
          return "Fault"
      }
    }              
  }
```

So when for example i set max: 1, then values have length 11 or when i set max: 3 then is 7.
Maybe is there a way to set number of Values this same as max property?